# Python 3.6 Generic Type Hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, types, type-hinting

I am trying to wrap my head around generic type hints. Reading over [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#defining-and-using-generic-types) in PEP 483, I got the impression that in

```
SENSOR_TYPE = TypeVar("SENSOR_TYPE")
EXP_A = Tuple[SENSOR_TYPE, float]
class EXP_B(Tuple[SENSOR_TYPE, float]):
    ...
```

`EXP_A` and `EXP_B` should identify the same type. In PyCharm #PC-181.4203.547, however, only `EXP_B`works as expected. Upon investigation, I noticed that `EXP_B` features a `__dict__` member while `EXP_A` doesn't.

That got me to wonder, **are both kinds of type definition actually meant to be synonymous?**

**Edit:** My initial goal was to design a generic class `EXP` of 2-tuples where the second element is always a `float` and the first element type is variable. I want to use instances of this generic class as follows

```
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class EXP_A(Tuple[T, float]):
    ...


EXP_B = Tuple[T, float]


V = TypeVar("V")


class MyClass(Generic[V]):
    def get_value_a(self, t: EXP_A[V]) -> V:
        return t[0]

    def get_value_b(self, t: EXP_B[V]) -> V:
        return t[0]


class StrClass(MyClass[str]):
    pass


instance = "a", .5

sc = StrClass()
a: str = sc.get_value_a(instance)
b: str = sc.get_value_b(instance)
```

([The section on user defined generic types](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) in PEP 484 describes this definition of `EXP` as equivalent to `EXP_B` in my original code example.)

The problem is that PyCharm complains about the type of `instance` as a parameter:

```
Expected type EXP (matched generic type EXP[V]), got Tuple[str, float] instead`. With `EXP = Tuple[T, float]` instead, it says: `Expected type 'Tuple[Any]' (matched generic type Tuple[V]), got Tuple[str, float] instead.
```

Comment: Can you show an example of `EXP_A` not working as expected?

Comment: @Aran-Fey when importing `EXP_A` and `EXP_B` in another file to use them like `class NewClassA(EXP_A[int]): ...` and `class NewClassB(EXP_B[int]): ...` PyCharm complains about the first opening square bracket after `EXP_A`. It says `Cannot find reference '[' in 'function | function'` but it has no problem with `EXP_B`.

Comment: Well, neither `EXP_A` nor `EXP_B` are generics, so it makes no sense to write `EXP_A[int]`. You wouldn't expect `Tuple[SENSOR_TYPE, float][int]` to work, would you? I have no idea why you're inheriting from `Tuple` anyway; are you sure you're using the `typing` module correctly...?

Comment: @Aran-Fey [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#defining-and-using-generic-types) in PEP 483 say that `Table = Dict[int, T]` *is* generic. The situation is the same with `EXP_A`. Furthermore [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) in PEP 484 says `class MyIter(Iterator[T]): ...` is equivalent to the *generic* `class MyIter(Iterator[T], Generic[T]): ...` which appears to be the same as with `EXP_B`. To answer your questions: 1. Actually I would assume that `int` fills in for the type variable. 2. That's what I want to find out.

Comment: The term "generic" is used for two different things here. `Table = Dict[int, T]` *is* generic in the sense that `Dict` accepts type arguments. But `Table` does *not* do that; `Table[int]` is an error. As for whether you're using the module correctly: We can't tell you that without knowing what you want to achieve. Subclassing generics is perfectly reasonable if you want to implement your own generic class. But if you're trying to use `typing` for *annotations*, then you're doing it wrong. We're going to need a [mcve] from you.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I added a use case example.

Comment: I suspect, but cannot confirm, that mypy, Pycharm, and other typecheckers do not handle complex type-alias expansions very gracefully at this present time. In any case, I would recommend you try filing an issue on Pycharm's issue tracker. It might also be worth checking to see if you get the same behavior while using mypy -- if so, I'd try either posting a question on mypy's issue tracker or try asking your question on the [Python typing gitter chat](https://gitter.im/python/typing). I don't think anybody on StackOverflow is going to be able to answer this question (and your previous one)

Answer (score 5):

I followed @Michael0c2a's advice, headed over to the python typing gitter chat, and asked the question there. The answer was that the example is correct.
From this, I follow that

1. `EXP_A` and `EXP_B` are indeed defining the same kind of types
2. PyCharm as of build #PC-182.4323.49 just doesn't deal with generic type annotations very well.